# How do you startup the additional cores on an Allwinner H5?

Tags: arm, embedded, cortex-a8, cortex-a

I am trying to figure out how to start cores other than core0 for a quad core allwinner h5.  the C_RST_CTRL register (a.k.a CPU2 Reset Control Register) has four bits at the bottom that imply they are four reset controls.  The lsbit is one the other three zeros implying setting those releases reset on the other cores, but I dont see that happening (nothing is running code I have left at address zero), at the same time zeroing that lsbit does stop core0 implying that it is a reset control.   So I assume there are clock gates somewhere but I cannot find them.

The prcm registers which are not documented in the H5 docs but are on a sunxi wiki page for older allwinners do show what seem to be real PLL settings but the cpu enable registers are marked as A31 only and the cpu0 register(s) are not setup so that would imply that is not how you enable any cpu including 0 for this chip.

What am I missing?

Comment: https://github.com/OrangePiLibra/OrangePi_H5SDK/tree/master/Documentation/Hardware it is the user manual that is the real manual with register specs.

Comment: Great. Thank you very much

Comment: the typical arm design is for the edge of the core to have individual clock enable and resets which are vendor specific as to how they are implemented.  arm generally does not and should not control those, wouldnt make sense.

Comment: @PeterJ I am reading it right now those look like signal names although they look to be in the arm's domain.  But I dont see any register connections with those names so there is an information gap there at the moment.

Comment: @PeterJ section A.3 in the TRM I am looking at (appendix A signal descriptions) nCORERESET for example are chip vendor supplied, so assume that is the C_RST_CTRL pins above, but bet there is something else....but for example the power management signals dont match the signals or bold type face registers/pins/bits you found.  so still a gap as to whom owns those signals you found and then where they are.

Comment: @PeterJ you probably noticed that the allwinner doc and the arm doc had the same picture with respect to the register/signals you mentioned.

Comment: I think those are just names of the power domains for discussion purposes, perhaps there are signals that are not in the documented signal list...PDCORTEXA53 PDL2 PDCPU PDCPUADVSIMD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a pure bare metal solution look at sunxi_cpu_ops.c from the plat/sun50iw1p1 directory of https://github.com/apritzel/arm-trusted-firmware.git

You need to deactivate various power clamps as well as clock gates.

Alternatively, include the Arm Trusted Firmware code and enable a core by an SMC call:

```
ldr x2,=entry_point
mov x1,#corenumber
mov x0,#0x03
movk x0,#0x8400,lsl #16
smc #0
```

I've now confirmed this works on an H5.

Answer (score 1):

Does C_CPU_STATUS STANDBY_WFI=0x0E suggest that the secondary cores are sitting in WFI?

Not an answer, I don't have enough rep to comment but I'm just starting the same exercise myself.

As an aside, how did you put code at address 0? Isn't that BROM? I was going to play with the RVBARADDR registers.

Comment: I am using u-boot to boot and loading at 0x42000000, have not replaced u-boot yet.

Comment: I'm just using the SPL from u-boot and loading an executable from there. Did you set up RVBARADDR?

Comment: 01700030 000E0000  yes STANDBY_WFI=0xE

Comment: could it be that "simple" though inject an interrupt into a core?

Comment: 017000A0 00010060 
017000A4 00000000

Comment: the AA64nAA32 bits are interesting as they are set for 32 bit mode, so u-boot starts 32 bit?  that doesnt make sense as we are in EL3 64 bit when handed off...and no setting those doesnt help...yet...

Comment: Definitely running AA64 in SPL and u-boot.

We may have to send an SGI to the core but it seems strange that the core doesn't just start when you de-assert RESET.

What's 0x01F01DA4?

Comment: Have you asked on #liunx-sunxi on IRC? They should have contacts who would know. I've not been able to find the part of the linux kernel that does this yet.

Comment: the h5 doc talks about a boot 0+ with a flowchart that includes after you determine you are not cpu0 then examine 0x01F01C00+0x1A4 for a soft reset entry point...

Comment: I have not tried the linux-sunxi folks yet, I assume you have not either...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149366/discussion-between-chris-fryer-and-old-timer).